# membership of level 2 vs. level 3 network

Tags: networking, router, lan

Managing computers for UNIFI routers "have to be in the same level 2 network" as the managed routers.
Is a computer behind the same internet modem router, but in a different IP-network, in the same level 2 network?
EG: 
Modem-Router, LAN-IP 192.168.1.0, serves 2 "sub"-routers, one with LAN-IP 10.10.10.0, the other with LAN-IP 10.200.200.0.

Is a computer in the 10.200.200.0 network in the same level 2 network as one in the 10.10.10.0 network???

I know, it is in a different level 3 (IP) network, but is it in the same level 2 network??

Chris

EDIT:
This is what it is about: 
I have a modem-router, to which I have attached several WiFi-APs, PLUS another LAN-Router for a local office network (cable based). The LAN-router is some sort of encapsulation of the office LAN from the WiFi-NW. 
Now I like to replace the WiFi-APs by UNIFI WiFi-APs to build up a managed wireless NW. These APs need a managing computer. 
As in the office-LAN there is already a server running 7x24 hours (just for local purposes, not accessible from the internet), it would be the easiest to use this one as controller instead of installing another 7x24 server just as WiFi manager. 
According to the UNIFI documentation, the controller has to be within the same layer 2 network.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the subnet mask used.  If the subnet of the 10.200.200.0 network AND the 10.10.10.0 network are both /8 subnet masks then **YES** they are part of the same LAYER 2 network and they are also part of the same LAYER 3 network as well.

However, your question really doesn't make much sense overall.  You would have no reason to create separate Layer 3 networks if the mask was a /8, and you can't have them in the same layer 2 network (`"have to be in the same level 2 network"`) if they aren't a /8.

Comment: Please re-read my (edited) initial post.
WiFi-AP's WAN-IP-addresses are 192.168.1.*/24,
LAN-IP-addresses of the "encapsulated" office-NW are 192.168.2.*/24.
Hope that helps you to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

1. It's `layer`, not `level`.
2. Can hosts which reside in different layer 3 networks be connected to the same layer 2 network? Yes, they can. If you have two hosts: 10.1.1.1/8 and 192.168.1.1/24 connected to the same physical switch then they are indeed connected to the same layer 2 network. Any layer two broadcasts sent from one host will be received by the other host and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, layer, of course...